# Spring IO Platform Cairo Release date with Springboot 2.0

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-io

When is the Spring IO Platform Release scheduled with the latest Springboot 2.0 and Webflux dependencies.
We are using Spring IO Platform Brussels SR4 in dependency management right now, and want to move to Reactive Springboot and Webflux. I think Spring IO Platform Cairo release should include these latest dependencies (correct me if I am wrong), but not sure of the release date for the same.

Comment: Spring Boot 2 isn't final yet so neither is the Cairo platform release. I guess it will follow as soon as Spring Boot 2 (and all referenced projects) are final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring IO Platform depends on a lot of Spring projects (obviously!) and has to wait for all releases.

You can check both [Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/milestones) and [Spring IO Platform](https://github.com/spring-io/platform/milestones) milestone pages to know more about this.